# Using PersistenceMapperWEBAPIClient

Tags: mdriven

If I change to PersistenceMapperWEBAPIClient:

this.PersistenceMapper = this.persistenceMapperWEBAPIClient1;

I get error message on start:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: "The file or assembly "Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream, Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" not found

/Efim

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to install Nuget Package with this assembly: solved.